# Format a number that can be variably rounded with thousand separator

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that ends up with a variable "dTot" which will be a number with up to 5 decimal places.

The user has an option to set the number of decimal places for rounding dTot, user selection is assigned to a variable "iDP", this can be anything between 0 and 5.

dTot = Round(dTot, iDP)` works just fine.

But, I also need to format the rounded number with thousand separator when adding to to another array.

`Format(Round(dTot, iDP), "#,##0.00000")`

works if iDP is 5, and

`Format(Round(dTot, iDP), "#,##0.00")`

if iDP is 2

How can I get the format to follow the iDP value?

I know I could use "Select Case iDP" and have 6 Cases, but since the formatting needs to be applied to up 6 expressions in each of 200 rows in the array I was hoping to find a way to avoid "Select Case"

Comment: OK, I solved it with a Function. Put the Select Case in a Public Function which takes iDP as an argument. The in main code use `sFmt = FmatStr(iDP)` Then for the formatting `Format(Round(dTot, iDP), sFmt)`

Comment: Let us see the Function.

Comment: `Public Function FmatStr(i As Integer) As String
    Select Case i
        Case Is = 0: FmatStr = "#,##0"
        Case Is = 1: FmatStr = "#,##0.0"
        Case Is = 2: FmatStr = "#,##0.00"
        Case Is = 3: FmatStr = "#,##0.000"
        Case Is = 4: FmatStr = "#,##0.0000"
        Case Is = 5: FmatStr = "#,##0.00000"
        Case Is = 6: FmatStr = "#,##0.000000"
    End Select
End Function`

Comment: user10825204's formula is much shorter and covers more decimals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build the format mask string as needed.

```
Format(Round(dTot, iDP), "#,##0" & IIF(iDP, ".", "") & string(iDP, "0"))
```

[image]

Comment: btw, The Round function may be redundant since the format mask 'rounds' the result to the specified decimals shown.

Comment: Thanks, user10825204, but using your formula, with iDP as 3 and dTot as 1569231622.7464 it returned 0 whereas my function returns 1,569,231,622.746 which is correct.

Comment: I had original mistyped a `,` for a `.` in `IIF(iDP, ".", "")`. I resolved within minutes of posting the reply but I guess you missed the correction.

Comment: OOOps my bad, I used dTot as an example here but in my actual code I have dTot1 through to dTot6, I copied your formula directly into my code and did not change dTot. As soon as I saw the formula I thought "That will work". Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Added the brilliant '`& IIF(iDP, ".", "")`' used in the accepted answer by [user10825204](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10825204/user10825204):**

## WorksheetFunction.Rept vs Replace(Space)

### WorksheetFunction.Rept

```
Format(Round(dTot, iDp), "#,##0" _
    & IIF(iDP, ".", "") & WorksheetFunction.Rept("0", iDp))
```

### Replace(Space)

```
Format(Round(dTot, iDp), "#,##0" _
    & IIF(iDP, ".", "") & Replace(Space(iDp), " ", "0"))
```

Comment: Both those also return 0 for the values shown in my comment to user10825204's answer above.

Comment: See my comment above, your formulas also work when I change dTot.